# Почему сервер возвращает Bad request? [400]

Tags: http, сокет

Отправляю серверу HTTP запрос такого вида (C++):

```
"GET /bot<api-code>/getMe HTTP/1.1\n"
                     "HOST: api.telegram.org\0";
```

Сервер отвечает 400 ошибкой. Так возникает с любым хостом, даже если после GET в URI я укажу просто слеш (/). Подскажите пожалуйста, почему так может быть (вместо API код стоит мой код, в браузере сервер отвечает нормально на такой запрос)

Comment: Запрос должен быть закончен двумя переводами строки. Ц вас ни одного. Более того, в http стандарте импользуется «досовский» вариант `\r\n` хотя современные сервера толерантны и скорее всего примут и просто `\n`

Comment: @AlexeyTen с переводами тоже не работало. Убрал "HTTP/1.1" и работает без переводов

Comment: Если с той стороны nginx, то такой запрос интерпретируется как http 0.9 и читается только одна первая строка